# Is df a mandatory param while using Re-rank query parser in solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using [Re-rank query parser](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/query-re-ranking.html) to re-rank documents from solr.

I am able to get the results of re-ranked query, when df param in passed in the lucene query

```
http://ip:port/solr/core/select?qt=dismax&q=mobile&rq={!rerank%20reRankQuery=$rqq%20reRankDocs=1000%20reRankWeight=3}&rqq=(red)&fl=display_query&df=query
```

Where as if we dont pass df param, the query is not working :

```
http://ip:port/solr/core/select?qt=dismax&q=mobile&rq={!rerank%20reRankQuery=$rqq%20reRankDocs=1000%20reRankWeight=3}&rqq=(red)&fl=display_query&df=query
```

Error thrown :

```
"error": {
"metadata": [
"error-class",
"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
"root-error-class",
"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError"
],
"msg": "org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Neither qf nor df are present.",
"code": 400
}
```

Not able to figure out the relation between rq(re-rank query) & df,  and why will it effect the way re-ranking works.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with reranking, but reranking still needs to consider a field, doesn't it? If one isn't set, it won't be able to properly determine what fields to search in. Also, does the error only occur with the re-rank-query present, or is the default search field missing altogether - i.e. for the dismax query itself?

Answer (score 2):

Got the reason behind this and how this can be solved, hope if helps someone else looking out for something similar.

When using reRankQuery, lucene's default query parser is used hence it does not know about df (even using qf paramter here wouldn't work here since it is understood only by dismax query parser). For any query when no parser is specified, it uses lucene's default query parser.

to force reRank to parse the query using dismax the syntax can be

```
http://ip:port/solr/core/select?qt=dismax&q=mobile&rq={!rerank%20reRankQuery=$rqq%20reRankDocs=1000%20reRankWeight=3}&rqq={!dismax}(red)&fl=display_query&df=query
```

Do check the [code](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/search/ReRankQParserPlugin.java#L64) to understand better

Comment: This really came as saviour when I had given hopes on reranking with edismax. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of trial and error, here is a way to use edismax with rerank in solr 9.3. I hope it helps someone.

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/myindex/select?fl=name%2Cdescription&q=laptop&qf=name%5E1.5%20description%5E1&rows=10&rq={!rerank%20reRankQuery%3D%24rqq%20reRankWeight%3D3}&rqq={!edismax}(apple)&defType=edismax'
```